# Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'student'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

My routing app-routing.module.ts

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes ,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { StudentComponent } from './student/student.component';
import { StudentdetailComponent } from './studentdetail/studentdetail.component';

const routes:Routes=[
{
  path:'student',component:StudentComponent
},
{
  path:'studentdetail',component:StudentdetailComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

student.component.html

```
<p>student works!</p>
```

studentdetail.component.html

```
<p>studentdetail works!</p>
```

test.component.html

```
 <a [routerLink] ="['/student']">Student</a><br/>
<a [routerLink] ="['/studentdetail']">Student Details</a><br/>

<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

appmodule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {Test} from './test.component';
import { TopComponent } from './top/top.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { StudentComponent } from './student/student.component';
import { StudentdetailComponent } from './studentdetail/studentdetail.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Test,
    TopComponent,
    StudentComponent,
    StudentdetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [Test]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I click on the link student and Student Details. I am getting below error after doing F12

**Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'student'
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'student'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AppModule.ts` you have to remove this line : `RouterModule.forRoot([])`

Then go to your `app-routing.module.ts` and put this line in the imports/exports :

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Add **export** to the routes in **app-routing.module.ts** and also exports **RouterModule** in exports array to be available in **other modules**:

```js
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

export const routes:Routes=[
{
  path:'student',component:StudentComponent
},
{
  path:'studentdetail',component:StudentdetailComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports : [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**import** the **exported routes in app module from app-routing.module.ts** :

```js
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([routes])
],
```